# Chrome Element Stuck After Append?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, append

I have run across a very strange issue to a seemingly simple piece of code. Here is an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jgqiu the code being reproducible with something like this:

HTML

```
 <nav class="pagination">
     <a href="#" class="dot active"></a>  </nav>

 <button>Add Dot</button>
```

CSS

```
.pagination {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.pagination .dot {
  background: #CCC;
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
}
.pagination .dot:only-child {
  display: none;
}
.pagination .dot.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

JS

```
$('button').click(function() {
  $(' <a href="#" class="dot"></a>').appendTo('.pagination');
});
```

Problem: In Chrome, the 2nd dot that is appended stays directly on top of the first, until you toggle any of the properties in the dev tools. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i may be misunderstood. If you try these codes it may be helpful.

```
.pagination .dot {
...
float:left;
}
```

and

```
.pagination {
    display: table;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```